# What property do you use to bind data to axml layout in MvvmLight?

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I've been for two whole days trying to figure out how do you bind data and commands to layout elements like a button or a listView and up until now I have had no success heres what I have as an example of one of my layouts.

Can you Help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/srlStores"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        local:MvxBind="Refreshing IsBusy">
        <MvxListView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lvStores"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Stores; ItemClick OpenDetailCommand"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/store_list_item" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        local:MvxBind="Visible IsBusy" />
    <Button
        android:text="@string/storeListCreateButtonText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bCreate"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        local:MvxBind="Click CreateCommand" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are extremely close. You have to make sure the ViewModel is setup properly, and then just go into the ViewModel that is associated with that Fragment which this Layout belongs to and for the button add this:

```
private IMvxCommand _createCommand;
public IMvxCommand CreateCommand
{
    get
    {
        return createCommand ?? (createCommand = new MvxCommand(() =>
            {
                // Do Some Work
            }));
    }
}
```

Similarly for your List, you need to create an ObservableCollection like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<StoreListModelWrapper> _stores;
public ObservableCollection<StoreListModelWrapper> Stores
{
    get { return _stores; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _stores, value); }
}
```

that will be called using the click command

```
public IMvxCommand<StoreListModelWrapper> _itemClickCommand;
public IMvxCommand<StoreListModelWrapper> ItemClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _itemClickCommand ?? (_itemClickCommand = new MvxCommand<StoreListModelWrapper>((item) =>  // Do Work with item.
                                   ));
    }
}
```